# How to solve equation that involves summation and integration both?

Tags: integration, summation, gamma-function

I am stuck with the following equation (1) that involves summation and integration both.

$$P_e = \sum_{i=0}^{M-r}b_{r,i}\int_0^\infty\!\!\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\gamma(p,qz)}{2\Gamma(p)}\right)\frac{e^{-\mu_{r,i}\sqrt{z}}}{2\sqrt{z}}\,dz \qquad(1)$$

where, $b_{r,i}$, $\mu_{r,i}$ do not depend on $z$. $p,q$ are positive constants. $\gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is lower incomplete gamma function.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not seeing an equals sign. How is this an equation? For what are you trying to solve?

Comment: Oh...my mistake...i forgot to add equals sign. Now it is corrected..

Comment: It's still by no means clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to solve for something? Or just compute the right-hand side?

Comment: The next step of eq (1) comes as $P_e = \frac{1}{2}-\sum_{i=0}^{M-r}b_{r,i}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\gamma(p,qz)}{2\Gamma(p)}\frac{e^{-\mu_{r,i}\sqrt{z}}}{2\sqrt{z}}dz$, where $b_{r,i}=r\zeta\binom{M}{r}(-1)^i\binom{M-r}{i}$. I am stuck in understanding how this step is obtained from eq (1).

Comment: Clearly it follows from $$\int_0^\infty \sum_{i=0}^{M-r} b_{r,i}\frac{e^{-\mu_{r,i}\sqrt{z}}}{2\sqrt{z}}\,dz = 1$$ but why that would be true depends on the definition of $\mu_{r,i}$, which you didn't provide.